# R: How to define partition to divide groups using 2 or more variables (multidplyr)

Tags: r

I have a problem with multidplyr. My raw data:

```
      warehouse quantity   stock_date flag_stock
1         a        1       2018-01-01     1
2         b        2       2018-01-01     0
3         a        0       2018-01-02     1 
4         a        2       2018-01-02     1
...

 cluster <- multidplyr::create_cluster(detectCores() - 1)
 set_default_cluster(cluster)
```

I want to aggregate data by warehouse and date_add using multidplyr:

```
warehouse.stock %>% 
multidplyr::partition(warehouse.stock, 
groups = c(warehouse, stock_date), cluster = cluster) %>% 
summarize(n = sum(quantity), disp = sum(flag_stock)) %>% 
collect()
```

But when I run the code I obtained this error message:

**Error: All partition vars must already exist**

Thanks!

Comment: You can e.g combine two columns into one by `unite(new_column, warehouse, stock_date)` and then `partition(new_column)`. Or use `group_by()` in combination with `nest()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your grouping variable must be in the original dataset, *stock_date* column does not appear in the dataset above.

Is this what you wanted?

```
warehouse.stock %>% 
multidplyr::partition(., 
groups = c(warehouse, date_add), cluster = cluster) %>% 
summarize(n = sum(quantity), disp = sum(flag_stock)) %>% 
collect()
```